# Upgrading from Qt 4.2.1 to Qt 4.6.1 changed the fonts

Tags: c++, qt, upgrade, backwards-compatibility

Just switched from Qt 4.2.1 to 4.6.1 and the fonts are different.  Different font type and size (bigger).

I did not regenerate any files just tried compiling with a different Qt version.

All the settings for the fonts, etc. are in the .cpp files.

Any ideas on how to change the fonts back?

I inherited the code and I'm not a Qt developer, if anyone can point me to some resources on this problem that would be great as well.

Comment: You may want to try running qtconfig too and see if the "environment" style configuration is impacting things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this might just be the danger of coding styles like fonts in source code rather than using [style sheets](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/stylesheet.html). When things change you'll need to add more source code but with style sheets any new stuff should get automatically covered by them provided they are applied on a wide enough scope. Only a guess though.

If your application is using a consistent font and font size throughout then a quick fix which might work is to try setting up an application-wide style sheet and setting it with [QApplication::setStyleSheet](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop). For example,

```
qApp->setStyleSheet( "*{ font-family: \"Times\"; font-size: 12pt }" );
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed a different issue using this.  The problem turned out to be new Qt was not compiled with the right styles (Solaris was missing).